# How to set row back color on certain row in SlickGrid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, slickgrid

I want to color the first 3 rows in SlickGrid to Blue. I would like to know the easy way to do so.

I tried following code but it doesn't work:

```
data.getItemMetadata = function (index)
{
   if (index == 0 || index == 1 || index == 2)
   {
       return  {cssClasses: "BlueColor"};
   }      
 }
```

Comment: Double check if `.slick-row.odd` and `.slick-row.even` are used in current page, which may overwrite BlueColor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS:

```
.slick-row:nth-child(-n+3){
    /*BlueColor class contents, if you place it before the .even and .odd classes you will need :important*/
}
```